# Lower Level Analysis of Using Return in Void Function

Tags: java

In Java, what happens on a low level when you use a `return;` statement in a `void` function, instead of letting the function end by reaching its end? Is there any difference?

For example, there might be some logical differences (and compile time isses), such as with

```
public void foo() {
    if (true) {
        return;
    }
    doSomething();
}
```

In which point we never execute `doSomething()`. However, that's **not** what I'm talking about. I'm talking about:

```
public void foo1() {
    doSomething();
    return;
}
```

vs

```
public void foo2() {
    doSomething();
}
```

Are there any differences with how this is handled at the machine level?

Comment: byte code of `foo1` & `foo2` are same when showing in intellij

Answer (score 2):

Referring to this [Oracle doc.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html) 
Any method that is declared as void doesn't return a value. 
Adding 'return' statement to such methods is optional. 
The only purpose of 'return' statement is just to branch out of a control flow block and exit the method.

```
public void foo1() {
    return;
    doSomething(); //compiler error.
}
```

Therefore,

```
public void foo1() {
    doSomething();
    return;
}
```

and

```
public void foo2() {
    doSomething();
}
```

are technically the same.